# LWC componet is not working properly cant figure it out , I just created a simple account creating lwc componet on my tab but then I notice this

Tags: lightning-web-components

[image: Screenshot]

Button is not responding as expected not even in inspect In fact i choose Brant as variant but as you can see on picture its not showing and not even responding any thing

**HTML**

```
<template>
    
       <!--<label class="slds-form-element__label">Enter your Name</label><br /> -->
        <lightning-input type="text" label="Enter the name" name="accountName" ></lightning-input> <br />
        <lightning-button varient="brant" label="Create" tittle="Create" onclick={accInsert}  class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
    
</template>
```

**JS**

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import Createacc from '@salesforce/apex/accIns.Createacc'
export default class AccountInsert extends LightningElement {

    accountName

    accInsert(){
        accountName=  this.template.queryLocator('lighting-input').value
        console.log(this.accountName);

        Createacc({ accName : this.accountName})
        .then((result) => {
            console.log("Result= "+ result);
        })
        .catch((error)=>{
            console.log("Error= "+error);
        })

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML, you have spelling mistakes. Such as  `varient="brant"`  which should be `variant="brand"`. Try copying things from component library, that will help in avoiding spelling mistakes.
And this also - `tittle="Create"` -> `title="Create"`

And in JS, you have syntax mistake & another spelling error in this line -

```
accountName=  this.template.queryLocator('lighting-input').value
```

it should be like this -

```
this.accountName = this.template.queryLocator('lightning-input').value
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I made spelling mistakes too in my answer :P